# Automatically Remove Overlap using Error Inspector

Tags: arcgis-pro, topology

I use Topology-rules and Error Inspector to remove errors in my map, duplicate lines etc.
I often have hundreds of small errors.

When available fixes are "Split" I can select all rows and fix them all.

[image]

But when the available fix is "Remove Overlap" I have to manually select each row, select "Remove Overlap" and then "Remove overlap" (preserve largest).

[image]

Is it possible to make a routine/script or something so I can select many rows, and then click just once, with preserve largest as default?

That would save me of a lot of time